# Teradata : Delete n rows from a table

Tags: teradata, sql-delete

I wanted to delete first n rows or last n rows from a table in Teradata. But I am not getting any correct query for doing this. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Define *first n rows*. There's no *first* or *last* row in a table, it's an unordered set of rows :-)

Comment: I mean to say any no of rows from beginning or last.

Comment: How do you define *beginning or last*?

Comment: Lets take an example that I wanted to delete 1/4 records from my table. How can I do this?

Comment: `delete from mytable where random(1,4) = 1` deletes approximately 25% randomly. But why would you do that?

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth the query runs fine. I am working on a Teradata project where I need to insert new data after removing few old data from the table. So I asked this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any experience in working with TeraData but if I am working with SQL I will make it like that :

```
Delete From |TableName| where |the ID column Name|
IN (Select top(n) |the ID column Name| from |TableName|)
```

So for example if I have a Customer Table and this table contains a CustomerID as Primary Key Column and CustomerName and I would like to Delete the First 10 rows i would be like that :

```
Delete From Customer  where CustomerID
IN (Select top(10) CustomerID  from Customer)
```

I hope it can help

Comment: Without an ORDER BY on CustomerID, TOP will return rows from the AMP that finishes first. This means a random result each time the query is executed. This may have undesirable consequences if run blindly in a production environment.

Comment: The above query did not worked and it shows an error: Top N is not supported in sub query

Answer (score 0):

Top N in subselect is restricted in delete, not in other context.

So, create a volatile table instead of subselect

```
create volatile table myDel as ( 
   select id from myTable
   sample .25
) with data on commit preserve rows;
delete T
from myTable T, myDel D
where T.id = D.id;
```

Will delete 25% of the data (BTW, sample has lot of options how to build the sample)

With volatile table and top n, and some order criteria you can clearly define what top/last is.

```
create volatile table myDel as ( 
     select top 3 id from myTable order by col_1
) with data on commit preserve rows;
```